# How to show current number of characters inside of textarea in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I try to show current number of characters inside a textarea, here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
  <textarea pInputTextarea placeholder="Write something..." 
      maxlength="50" (keydown.backspace)="onKeydown($event)"
      (keypress)="maxLenght($event)" formControlName="addNotes" class="addNotes">
  </textarea>
  <span>{{notesLength}}/50</span> 
</div>
```

**Typescript**

```
notesLength: number;
...
maxLenght(event: any) {
  console.log('Key press', event);
  this.notesLength = event.target.textLength;
}

onKeydown(event: any) {
  this.notesLength = event.target.textLength;
}
```

The problem here is when I type the first letter even though the `console.log()` shows that the `event.target.textLength` is `1` the value of `this.notesLength` remains `0` and always when typing the `this.notesLength` is one character behind. Can anyone explain this and maybe give my any help?

Comment: change `keyPress` to `keyUp`. If you are not happy with the result just go back to `keyDown` and then `this.notesLength = event.target.textLength + 1`

Comment: @JacopoSciampi thanks a lot mate. The `keyup` is the answer and it works like a charm. You can write the answer below in order to vote it. Chears!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using `keydown`. This even will fire the callback before the key value is registered in the `text-area`.

To fix this simply change to event to `keyUp`. This event, instead, will fire the callback after the value is registered in the `text-area` and your total will show exactly the excepted result.

> Bonus Tip

Using `keyUp` will also handle properly some operations like deleting one character at time or, for example, with some combinations like `CTRL + A` -> `backspace` / `canc` / `CTRL + X`

Comment: I would suggest to monitor the `input` event instead of `keyup`. That will account for changes made not only with the keyboard but also with menu commands (cut, delete, paste).